# How to use eval function in laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In controller I have eloquent query wrapped as string. I want to execute it as a code with eval. Here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Pc;
use App\Http\Requests\StorePcRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdatePcRequest;
use App\Models\Product;

class PcsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $query = "Pc::where('speed', '>', 500)->get(['model', 'price'])";

    eval("return $query;");
}
```

but in here's error in browser: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2djTq.png). Class 'Pc' not found

How can i use it properly?

Comment: Any specific reason the use `eval` and not run the query as usual?

Comment: What is you goal?

Comment: @Maik Thank you! But I need to use exactly eval. exercise says save eloquent query in variable as a string and execute it as a code.

Comment: @NikaSimonishvili ok. thanks for feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error occurs why laravel dont found the model PC. Use the full path: `\App\Models\PC::where('speed', '>', 500)->get(['model', 'price'])->get();` for example. your path can be different.
I added get() maybe you havce to remove because you concatinate on other place.

### Update

Change it to `return  eval("return $query;");` then you will get data.

Comment: I tried this: `$query = "\App\Models\Pc::where('speed', '>', 500)->get(['model', 'price'])";` error disappeared but there is no data, just blank screen ;(

Comment: Is everything right inside the eval function? ` eval("return $query;");`

Comment: @NikaSimonishvili its look good. that is a `string`.  You have any data in your database? you can using the query first without using eval. intressting question. please share your result and feedback..!

Comment: @NikaSimonishvili I tried and i got the values. Take a look that you are using the right path to your model. in my case woul be `\App\Models\MyModel::get();` Try again :-)

Comment: yes I have data in DB. When I try with regular query, it shows. ok, thanks for help. I`ll post when I fix this.

Comment: @NikaSimonishvili i updated my answer. i found your problem. only add return before you execute eval.